# What is $x$, if $\cot ^{-1} \left(3x+\frac{2}{x}\right)+\cot ^{-1} \left(6x+\frac{2}{x}\right)+\cot ^{-1} \left(10x+\frac{2}{x}\right)+\cdots = 1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, telescopic-series

> Let
>
> $$S_{n}=\cot ^{-1} \left(3x+\frac{2}{x}\right)+\cot ^{-1} \left(6x+\frac{2}{x}\right)+\cot ^{-1} \left(10x+\frac{2}{x}\right)+\cdots \quad\text{($n$ terms)}$$
> where $x>0$. If $\lim _{n \to \infty} S_{n}=1$, then  find the value of $x$.

Can the given series be converted to telescopic series? I converted in into $\tan^{-1}$ but in every term $x$ is in numerator? Could someone please given some hint?

Comment: So the progression for $x$ is $$3,6,10,15,\;\text{triangular numbers?}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cot^{-1}(A)-\cot^{-1}(B)=\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{AB+1}{B-A} \right).
\end{eqnarray*}
In your case this gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{i(i+1)x}{2}+\frac{2}{x} \right)=\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{ix}{2} \right)-\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{(i+1)x}{2} \right).
\end{eqnarray*}
So the sum is telescopic and we get $\color{red}{x=\cot(1)}$.

Comment: Very nice. My answer is definitely wrong.

Comment: Are you sure? I got $$1 = \lim_n [\cot^{-1}(\frac{(1)x}2) - \cot^{-1}(\frac{(n+1)x}2)]$$ Or does your $i$ start at $i=2$? I actually got $$\begin{eqnarray*}
\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{(i+2)(i+1)x}{2}+\frac{2}{x} \right)=\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{(i+1)x}{2} \right)-\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{(i+2)x}{2} \right).
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 0):

Arguing loosly,

$\begin{array}\\
S_n
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} arccot(\frac{(i+1)(i+2)x}{2}+\frac{2}{x})\\
&\approx \frac{2}{x}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac1{(i+1)(i+2)}
\qquad\text{since }arccot(x) \approx \frac1{x} \text{ for large } x \\
&=\frac{2}{x}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\dfrac1{i+1}-\dfrac1{i+2})\\
&=\frac{2}{x}(\frac12-\frac1{n+2})
\\
&=\frac1{x}-\frac{2}{x(n+2)})
\\
\end{array}
$

So if $S_n \to 1$,
must have $x = 1$.

It would be entertaining 
if this sloppy argument
was correct.

Comment: And of course this is wrong. See Donald Splutterwit's answer.